# PHP & MySQL, Database Optimization

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database project in php and MySql. Where I am sotring students data according to the subject they have opted to learn. I have created Attendance Module where each subject daily attendance is saved in another subject wise table. Now I want to create a Score Board in which each subect wise Test Marks will be uploaded and I think I now require Another same no. of tables as the subject are.. In short  I Have 8 Subject..8 table already there for students choices..8 again I created for subject wise attendance. and I need further 8 for score of test. Means at the end I am creating a database of 24 Tables. Is it optimized way...I am confused..Kinndly suggect me the optimized wat for it...

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. If you have a specific query / problem, then feel free to ask, but asking for an optimised solution with no obvious effort put in isn't going to happen.

Comment: No, it is definitely not optimised this way. You only need a single table for choices, another one for attendance, and another one for test marks. Use the identifier from the subjects table in the above mentioned tables to relate them to a subject.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way: By using data models, you can create such data in 4 tables:
1. User table - userid, username, userregno, classno
2. subjects table - subjectid, subjectname, subjectcode
3. testmarks table - testmarkid, userregno, subjectcode, testmark
4. score board table - scoreboardid, scoreboardcode, classno

That will help you to create anytype of report.